# Helm: Is it wise to commit the .helm folder to source control?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When I use helm, It creates a `.helm` folder in my home directory.  Is it important? Should it be committed to source control?  Poking around I only see cache related information, that makes me think the whole folder can be deleted.  And helm will re-create it if needed.  Am I wrong in this thinking? Or is there something important in those folders that is worth putting into source control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, no.

The `.helm` directory contains user specific data that will depend on the version of helm, the OS being used, the layout of the user’s system.

However, the main reason to not add it is that it also can contain TLS secrets which would then be disclosed to other users. Worse, if you use Git, these secrets would remain in the history and would be hard to remove, even if you deleted the `.helm` directory at a later date.

Comment: Just to complement the answer, think `~/.helm` directory is similar to your `~/.gitconfig`, that stores some sensitive data that should be important only to you.